# Ubuntu doesn’t recognize USB’s anymore?

Tags: usb

Like the title says, Ubuntu has stopped recognizing any USB drive I insert. It worked just fine a few days ago? It does recognize my phone when it’s plugged in so I’m not sure what’s going on. All of my USB ports work, I made sure to check that first. I clearly wasn’t able to format via USB so I deleted the partitions I had and re-installed Ubuntu all together and STILL it doesn’t recognize any of my USB’s ): I also formatted my USB’s in my other OS before I even tried to use them. Help!

Comment: Please, add output of the lsusb command before and after inserting the USB drive.

Comment: There is not enough information here to offer any specific solutions. Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you’re running (1) the brand and model of your computer (2) the brand and model of the USB storage devices you’re trying to use. With this, in addition to the output of `lsusb` as Mahler requested, it may be possible to suggest a solution.